# My React code breaks on Refresh. How can I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, refresh

When I refresh the page, I know that useState() will go back to the default value. What kind of conditional logic can I use to prevent my codes from breaking while the defaults are being replaced through useEffect()?

ContentContext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ErrorContext } from "./ErrorContext";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";

const ContentContext = createContext({});
const ContentProvider = ({children}) => {
    const { setErrors } = useContext(ErrorContext);
    const { loggedIn } = useContext(UserContext);
    const [contents, setContents] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/posts')
        .then(resp => {
            if (resp.ok) {
                resp.json().then(data => {
                    setContents(data);
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(errors => {
            setErrors(errors);
        });
    }, [setErrors, loggedIn])

    const addPost = (newPost) => {
        setContents([...contents, newPost]);
    }

    const editPost = (newPost) => {
        const updatedContentList = contents.map(post => {
            if (newPost.id === post.id) {
                return newPost
            } else {
                return post;
            }
        });
        setContents(updatedContentList);
    }

    const deletePost = (id) => {
        const updatedContentList = contents.filter(post => post.id !== id)
        setContents(updatedContentList);
    }

    return (
        <ContentContext.Provider value={{ contents, addPost, editPost, deletePost }}>{ children }</ContentContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { ContentContext, ContentProvider }
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './pages/Navbar';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import PostList from './posts/PostList';
import PostDetail from './posts/PostDetail';
import EditPost from './posts/EditPost';
import Home from './pages/Home';

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/posts" element={<PostList />} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id/edit" element={<EditPost/>} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id" element={<PostDetail />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PostList.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './pages/Navbar';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import PostList from './posts/PostList';
import PostDetail from './posts/PostDetail';
import EditPost from './posts/EditPost';
import Home from './pages/Home';

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/posts" element={<PostList />} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id/edit" element={<EditPost/>} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id" element={<PostDetail />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PostCard.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function PostCard ({ post }) {

    return (
        <div className="box-3">
            <h4><Link className="title-link" to={`/posts/${post.id}`}>{post.title}</Link></h4>
            <h5>- {post.creator.username}</h5>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostCard;
```

PostDetail.js

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { ContentContext } from "../context/ContentContext";
import { UserContext} from "../context/UserContext";
import CommentList from "../comments/CommentList";
import { ErrorContext } from "../context/ErrorContext";

function PostDetail () {
    const { setErrors } = useContext(ErrorContext);
    const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
    const { contents, deletePost } = useContext(ContentContext);
    const { id: paramsId } = useParams();
    const id = parseInt(paramsId);
    const post = contents.find(post => post.id === id);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [commentMode, setCommentMode] = useState(false);
    const openComment = () => setCommentMode(commentMode => !commentMode);
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);
    const params = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`)
        .then(resp => {
            if (resp.ok) {
                resp.json().then(data => {
                    setLiked(data.liked);
                });
            } 
        })
        .catch(errors => {
            setErrors(errors);
        });
    }, [post.id, setErrors])

    const handleLike = () => {
        fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                setLiked(true);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setErrors(error)
        });
    }

    const handleUnlike = () => {
        fetch(`/posts/${post.id}/likes/${params.id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                setLiked(false);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setErrors(error)
        });
    }

    const onDeletePost = () => {
        fetch(`/posts/${post.id}`, {
            method: "DELETE",
        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(deletePost(post.id))
        .then(navigate(`/posts`))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="box-2">
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                <h5>{post.creator.username}</h5>
                <p>{post.content}</p>
                {liked ? (
                    <button className="edit-btn" onClick={handleUnlike}>Unlike</button>
                ):(
                    <button className="edit-btn" onClick={handleLike}>Like</button>
                )}
                <button className="edit-btn" onClick={openComment}>Comments</button>
                {user && user.username === post.creator?.username && (
                    <>
                    <button className="edit-btn"><Link to={`/posts/${post.id}/edit`}>Edit</Link></button>
                    <button className="edit-btn" onClick={onDeletePost}>Delete</button>
                    </>
                )}
                <br /><br />
            </div>
            <br />
            <hr />
            <br />
            <div>
                {commentMode && <CommentList post={post}/>}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostDetail;
```

Inside PostList.js, I grabbed contents from ContentContext.js and map() to render a list of all posts with each post individually inside PostCard.js.

Then, in PostCard.js, I made each post.title a clickable link that takes me to PostDetail.js which is where all the content, comments, and likes are.

In PostDetail.js, every time I refresh the page => the code breaks.

Everything else works flawlessly.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code breaks because during the initial render

```
const post = contents.find(post => post.id === id);
```

`post` is undefined.

Then, in the `return` statement of `PostDetail` component, we try to get a property of `undefined` (`post.title`), which will raise a TypeError exception.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

To solve the problem, you can add an if-else for the `PostDetail` component to return `null` (or some fancy loading animation) when post is `undefined`.